# faster way for setting up xticks using matplotlib

Tags: windows, python-2.7, matplotlib

I am working on a project which make use of Python-2.7, pygtk and matplotlib-2 on windows.

My app records data from COM port and plot it like a live plot. I need to put major and minor ticks for grid purpose.

My X-axis data is time duration in seconds.

```
ax1.set_xticks(np.arange(x_range[0],x_range[1],0.45))
ax1.set_xticks(np.arange(x_range[0],x_range[1],0.09),minor=True)
```

major ticks @ 0.45 sec.
minor ticks @ 0.09 sec

x_range[0] is minimum value of x axis data

x_range[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFsAn.png) is maximum value of x axis data

Setting ticks this way is taking more time and also it takes lot of time when I plot entire data.

Is there any faster way to set ticks using matplotlib?

Note: I have totally 7 different data sets to be plotted on different subplots.

Sample plot image is given blow.

In following image, you can see grid properly. This plot window is also with a scroll bar at bottom. Total plot size depends on total time of data recording.

[image]

Comment: The problem is not the time it takes to set the ticks. In any case it would be the time to *draw* the ticks that is bothering you. Even using a different approach to set the ticks, the time to draw them is much longer than any setting method. Without a clear description of the actual plot that is produced, it's not actually possible to tell if faster solutions exist or not.

Comment: From the plot you show it's not clear why you would need to repeatedly set the ticks at all. I would also doubt that drawing the ticks slows down your plotting significantly.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest , i think, this new image will give u better idea.